# Issue with Network IP Binding

Tags: networking, centos6, ip-address, bindings

Trying to bind a /29 (my possession, not the ISP or data center). It's routed at my core switch fine.

```
interface Vlan70
description SERVER070
ip address xxx.xxx.42.45 255.255.255.248
```

Content of: /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0-range0

```
IPADDR_START=xxx.xxx.42.47
IPADDR_END=xxx.xxx.42.50
CLONENUM_START=1
```

Content of: /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0

```
DEVICE=eth0
HWADDR=00:12:3F:20:72:EA
TYPE=Ethernet
UUID=e9a8c070-e280-4586-bd89-d1f4c758c205
ONBOOT=yes
NM_CONTROLLED=yes
BOOTPROTO=static
IPADDR=xxx.xxx.42.46
GATEWAY=xxx.xxx.42.45
NETMASK=255.255.255.248
```

IFCONFIG OUTPUT

```
[root@localhost ~]# ifconfig
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:12:3F:20:72:EA  
          inet addr:xxx.xxx.42.46  Bcast:xxx.xxx.42.47  Mask:255.255.255.248
          inet6 addr: fe80::212:3fff:fe20:72ea/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:926892 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:1074666 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:143335504 (136.6 MiB)  TX bytes:177454986 (169.2 MiB)

eth0:1    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:12:3F:20:72:EA  
          inet addr:xxx.xxx.42.47  Bcast:xxx.xxx.42.47  Mask:255.255.255.248
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1

eth0:2    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:12:3F:20:72:EA  
          inet addr:xxx.xxx.42.48  Bcast:xxx.xxx.42.47  Mask:255.255.255.248
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1

eth0:3    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:12:3F:20:72:EA  
          inet addr:xxx.xxx.42.49  Bcast:xxx.xxx.42.47  Mask:255.255.255.248
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1

eth0:4    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:12:3F:20:72:EA  
          inet addr:xxx.xxx.42.50  Bcast:xxx.xxx.42.47  Mask:255.255.255.248
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
          RX packets:165 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:165 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:72952 (71.2 KiB)  TX bytes:72952 (71.2 KiB)
```

I'm running Centos 6.5 64bit and yes, I have run service network restart without errors. I cannot ping the IPs nor get them bound correctly for whatever strange reason.

```
[root@localhost ~]# nc -s xxx.xxx.42.50 www.google.com 80 -vv
nc: connect to www.google.com port 80 (tcp) failed: Connection timed out
```

Comment: Your CentOS config looks fine. Check your firewall and router.

Comment: Isn't the subnet wrong? shouldn't it be .40 to .47 ?

Comment: My apology, was a typo in the subnetting, yes. I fixed it. Thanks.

Comment: happens :) at least it works now :)